# How to execute some certain set of statements once a Ctrl+C is done for a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app running which also is creating containers. Once I press Ctrl+C, I want any running containers to be killed.

I already have a function defined which kills running containers and it works.It's called remove_con(port_number)

I have a list of active ports on which my containers are running.

When I do Ctrl+C, I want to iterate through that list and call remove_con for each port. And then the program should stop

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library in python called atexit. You can use that library to call cleanup function before the program closes.

```
import atexit
ll=[1,2,3,4,5]

def remove_numbers(ll):
    for i in ll:
        ll.remove(i)


if __name__="__main__":
    atexit.register(remove_numbers,ll)  #first argument is the function name followed
                                        #by all the params
```

You can do this for more than one function.

Reference: https://pymotw.com/2/atexit/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. You will have to use signal for capturing force shutdown of the application and then pass the handler for the functionality.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT